# How do i pass data received from angular to html front-end?

Tags: json, angular

this is my angular service:

```
@Injectable()
 export class ApiService {
  private get_msg_url: string = "http://localhost:3000/getmessages";
     constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

     getMessage(): Observable<IPosts> {
      return this.http.post<IPosts>(this.get_msg_url,{"data":"data1"});
    }
   }
```

this is my message.component.ts :

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
     data = [];
     iposts: IPosts[];
     constructor(private apiSerivce: ApiService) {
     }
     getMessage(): void {
         this.apiSerivce.getMessage()
             .subscribe(data1 => this.data.push(data1));
     }
     ngOnInit(): void {
         this.getMessage();
         console.log(this.data);
     }
 }
```

this is my posts.ts:

```
export interface IPosts {
    timestamp : number;
    message_content : string;
    message_link :string;
    tags : string[] ;
}
```

this is messsage.component.html:

```
<p>Json data {{data}} </p>
```

whenever the code is run i can see the required data in console of chrome but there is no data shown on page.
the data received on console is of form:

```
[]
    0: 
    message: Array(3)
        0: {timestamp: 1522072833748, 
        tags: Array(2), _id: "5aacb7cc0281b558debacf26", 
       message_link:"String"
    }}
```

Comment: Print out your data into console.log, and what is the result?
could you show the output?

Comment: Sidenote: You are very lucky if your `console.log(this.data);` gives you result as this is asynchronous, so just a reminder, do not expect to always have the result available there :)

Comment: `this.getMessage();
  console.log(this.data);`
This is pretty much useless, as getMessage is an async call, and therefore, the console.log will print an empty array all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, that you try to print an array, instead of the elements.

```
<p>Json data {{data}} </p>
```

change this to something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let element of data; index as i">
  Json data #{{i}}: {{element]]
</p>
```

Comment: This works but I prefer the `{{data | json}}` solution

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, data is an array. you can display the raw content of an array with the pipe json : `{{data | json}}`
However I am not sur what you want to do with a json displayed in your html.

Comment: No problem, can you mark this as answered ?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your output data is an array, not an element.
Try something like this,

```
<ul *ngFor="let element of data">
  <li>{{element}}</li>
</ul>
```